# How to force-close when error message keeps popping

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-3, force-close

I'm new to Android development.

I wrote a funny app which endlessly pops messages saying "Unfortunately, YOUR_FREAKING_APP has stopped." on launch.

To force-close it, I held down the *Home* button but the *Recent Apps* doesn't show while the message box is active. Another message box shows after I touch 'OK' roughly in 500ms.

Workarounds I've found so far:

- Close the message box and hold down the *Home* button as quickly as possible. → rarely works.
- 1. Connect the device to PC and open *Notifications*, then touch 'Connected as a media de...' to switch to 'USB computer connection'.
  2. After switching, the mesage box doesn't show up any more.
  3. Touch 'OK' and adios. → this works but what if away from PC?
- Restart

Are there any other methods to force close?

Comment: Well, I guess restart / shutdown is a very obvious solution.

Comment: Usually, for me, this loop is either fixed by somehow managing to force stop the app (rarely if ever works) or restarting the device. If an app does it a few times, it gets uninstalled.